# Is it possible to find a random process such that it is stationary in the autocorrelation function but not stationary in the mean?

Tags: correlation

My intuition suggests that if a random process is not stationary in the mean, since it is not WSS there is no practicality in looking at other stationarities in the engineering sense. But I am mathematically curious anyway.

Comment: In the older engineering literature, _"Stationary in the mean"_  often meant a random process that was stationary to order 2 (but not necessarily strictly stationary) and also had a finite variance (so that a sequence of iid Cauchy random variables was not stationary in the mean but a sequence of iid normal random variables was stationary in the mean. As Alex's answer shows, it is still possible for an autocorrelation function to share the WSS property that $R_X(t_1,t_2) = R_X(0, t_2-t_1)$ without needing to meet the $E[X_t]=\mu$ standard for WSS processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_t=t+N_t$, where $N_t$ is an iid standard normal. Then $E[X_t]=t\neq E[X_0]=0$, yet the autocorrelation 0 since each $X_i$ is independent of the last.